# Looking for a word for animals that defecate anywhere

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, animals, scientific-language

There is a word for animals like horses and cows that defecate wherever they happen to be when the need strikes them, versus animals like dogs and cats that seek out one place or another to do their business. It may be that all such animals are herbivores but "herbivore" is not the word I'm looking for as it relates to eating habits rather than pooping habits.

Comment: I've added [the SWR tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), since it seems to fit your question. However, why are you sure that such a word exists (as you suggest in your first sentence)? (The DV wasn't mine, BTW.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I came across the word a few months ago. I was trying to remember it today but drawing a blank. I think it starts with a D but wouldn't swear to it.

Comment: And dogs and cats, for example, have related instinctive rituals that herbivores don't.

Comment: @TimR Many herbivores (think horses and goats) are highly intelligent and can be trained to do any other type of trick. Some can be *partially* house trained, that is, urine only. Being fully house trained, however, requires muscles those animals don't have ([anal sphincter muscles?](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8760483)).

Comment: @Laurel: Cows go even when they're lying down. Here's a title of a scientific article that would make for a good prepositional phrase question on ELL:  *Individual and environmental factors associated with defecation while lying down in dairy cows*

Comment: @Graffito — Horses aren’t ruminants.

Comment: There is no zoological term for pooping habits. It is default behavior in animals with few exceptions like dogs and cats where dogs are house-trained and cats have an evolutionary instinct to excrete within a substrate. Other pets can be house-trained also and I saw an article where cows were potty-trained as well. _Self-anointing_ is a term for animals that smear odoriferous substances on their bodies, which can include their excretions, so they can just randomly excrete to anoint themselves.

Comment: Also, someone asked this on theNakedScientist  before: " Why do some animals defaecate indiscriminately?" https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/why-do-some-animals-defaecate-indiscriminately

Comment: Bowel control. Maybe not a merely zoological term, but I found several usages of this term in scholarly research on animals.

Comment: 'Open defecation' seems to be applied only to humans defecating in the outdoors.